# Minecraft won't let me log in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft has not been letting me log in since yesterday. I have no idea why. When I logged off of a server I was gonna get back on but I closed minecraft. When I went back on it wanted me to log in. I had no idea why so I put my account in and it said "could not log in as -Minecraft name-, please try again" I had no idea why. Today it still isn't working. I tried getting on MineChat too and that didn't work. Please help.

Btw this is what its doing when I try to change it https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ipAR.jpg

Comment: It seems like either you were using an account of someone else (< agaisnt mojang account ToS) and your account got hacked. Try resetting your password if you own the account and try buying an actual account if you don't.

Comment: You may have better luck contacting Mojang support for accessing your account.

Comment: You should always record your passwords in a non-virtual source (e.g. a notepad) so while you have it recorded, it cant get stolen or data-mined. Also, spelling is very important. Remember your username and password well, and you will be all good.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, the provided image states that the password you're trying to use has a word that's been blacklisted (ie, cannot be used)  This most likely means that you contain a word like "Password" or "ABC" in your password that is very common.  Try to use a better combination of characters that do not match common dictionary words.

---

From there, while we can't figure out why a username/password is not working, (as no one here works for Mojang), I would suggest you take a moment to consider if you logged into any websites or services recently using the same account as your MineCraft account.  Some (but not all) of the cases we have about username/passwords not working tend to come back to people logging into an unofficial "minecraft" services that's stealing accounts in the background.  It's easy to get your account back, but the time it takes to recover it usually means someone has a dummy account they can mess with for hours until the owner fixes the issue.

This is very unlikely, but not impossible nor as uncommon not to be mentioned.  It's more likely that it's just an issue with the password being typed incorrectly too many times, but barring that problem and any issue with the logon servers having issues, this is the next possible problem.